# libGDX: Как увеличить интервал между появлением объектов?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Не могу понять - как увеличить интервал, т.е. частоту вызова метода. Мне в идеале нужно сделать его равным экрану, т.е. `Gdx.graphics.getWidth() + х` . За х берется рандомное число. Может быть есть какой-то другой, альтернативный способ?

```
private long lastDropTime;    
    lastDropTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
    
   
 public void render () {
           ...
        
      
if(TimeUtils.nanoTime() - lastDropTime > 1000000000) {
       spawnRaindrop(); //вызов метода
       }
       ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой способ это использовать класс Timer

```
Timer.Task task = new Timer.Task() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        spawnRaindrop();
    }
}

float intervalSeconds = 5f;
timer.scheduleTask(task, intervalSeconds, intervalSeconds);
```